# Accordion in coreui Angular 6

Tags: angular, core-ui

I have a clean Angular coreui template. I can see many bootstraps components are working as expected. I am trying to implement an accordion menu:

```
<button class="btn btn-square btn-primary btn-next"
        [disabled]="!canContinueFromSocialNetwork" 
        (click)="loadAgeRangeList()" 
        type="button" 
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseAge" aria-expanded="true">Next</button>
```

And then the accordion:

```
<div id="collapseAge" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">..
```

When clicking the button no errors are thrown, but the accordion doesn't trigger. When working in Angular do you need to import and components to work with a simple bootstrap accordion?

I tried just making a new simple component with following html:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Provide more codes of yours to debug your issue.

Comment: I just tried adding a new component and added accordion shown in original post. coreui is using bootstrap all over, and I cannot see any includes of bootstrap in the index.html. So I am not really sure how else it can be added. I am very new to Angular.

Comment: It seems Angular has its own way og making collapse compoenents with "ngx-bootstrap/collapse".